# How to execute python statement for each line?

Tags: vimscript-python

I've the following sample code which modifies the current line using Python statement:

```
:py import vim; vim.current.line="["+vim.current.line+"]"
```

How I can execute this statement for each line in the current file?

Related: [How can you use Python in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim) at stackoverflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `pydo` command available since Vim 7.4, the manual describe how it works better than I could:

> :[range]pydo {body}
>
> Execute Python function "def _vim_pydo(line, linenr): {body}" for each
>   line in the [range], with the function arguments being set to the text
>   of each line in turn, without a trailing <EOL>, and the current line
>   number. The function should return a string or None. If a string is
>   returned, it becomes the text of the line in the current turn. The
>   default for [range] is the whole file: "1,$".

For your example you can use a command like:

```
:python import vim
:pydo vim.current.buffer[linenr - 1] = '[%s]' % line
```

The `linenr - 1` bit is there because lines in `vim.current.buffer` are 0-indexed but Vim start to count lines from 1.

The nice thing is that you can easily define a custom command to execute your Python code on a range of lines:

```
command! -range=% BracketLines 
    \ <line1>,<line2>pydo vim.current.buffer[linenr - 1] = '[%s]' % line
```

Comment: It's available since vim 7.4.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current buffer with `vim.current.buffer`, which is an iterable; you can use use a `for` loop to get each line.

You can change the lines by assigning to them; so putting that together, we get:

```
:py from vim import *
:py for i, line in enumerate(current.buffer): current.buffer[i] = '[%s]' % line
```

Also see [`:help python-buffer`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html#python-buffer).